# How to add both text and images into textbox

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I add both text and images into chat box? I got this question when I thinked of the Facebook chatbox.

Comment: I dont understand exactly what you mean by textbox. Please could you add code to your question to make it clearer. This should help with that: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Im just assuming the Facebook chat box is a textbox, after reading the answers I think I'll edit my question

Comment: AFAIK textbox isn't an element type. What I'm confused about is what sort of element you are talking about. It sounds as though it's just a div to which img elements can be added alongside text.

Comment: I talk about Facebook's chatbox, and my question is how do they make it that, when I capture screen picture then Paste into the chat box, it actually receiving that image and I can also type text. I want to know why is that and how can I do reproduce that for my chat box

Comment: Have a look via your browser's dev tools inspect facility to see how they set up that element. Sounds like a div with text in it and img elements.

Comment: make sense very much, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In facebook's chatbox, there's no `textarea` it's a div, also if you are making an input which contains images you could use quill.js

Answer (score 2):

If you use an image inside a text area field, you have to use this:

```
<p><img src="ENTER URL HERE" height="ENTER HEIGHT HERE" width="ENTER WIDTH HERE"></p>
```

Comment: Hi, what is a text area field? I assume it's not a textarea element? Is it a parent div element for example?

Comment: it is textarea html tag

Comment: How are you getting it to accept HTML? It could be useful if you added a bit more of the HTML ina working snippet to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.tiny.cloud/ or other similar javascript libraries to customize `textarea` html tag.